# Typesafe deep object property access

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a method for updating nested object property :

```
import * as set from 'lodash/fp/set';

class Foo {
  private object: any;

  updateDeepObjectProperty<T, K1 extends keyof T, K2 extends keyof T[K1]>(objectType: T, path: [K1, K2], value: T[K1][K2]);
  updateDeepObjectProperty<T, K1 extends keyof T>(objectType: T, path: [K1], value: T[K1]);
  updateDeepObjectProperty<T>(objectType: T, path: any, value: any) {
    this.object = set(path, value, this.object);
  }
}


interface ObjectInterface {
  deep: {
    property: number;
  }
}

class Bar {
  private foo = new Foo();
  private objectType: ObjectInterface;

  onUpdateThing(value: number): void {
    this.foo.updateDeepObjectProperty(this.objectType, ['deep', 'property'], value);
  }
}
```

I'm trying to infer K... with overloading without having to pass objectType parameter but typescript complains about missing type arguments.

Is there any way to add ObjectInterface as type argument but keep inferring K1... ?

Comment: If your question is about specifying `T` manually but having the compiler infer `K1` and `K2`, then I'm inclined to close this as a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57135846/make-overpropobj-function-interface-with-one-param) or similar.  If your question is about something else, please elaborate how it is different from the above.  Good luck!

Comment: Also, code included in questions should ideally constitute a [mcve], where the only issues present are the ones you are facing.  In the code here there's invalid syntax (e.g., `Class`) and missing declarations (e.g., `foo`, `object`, `_set`, `ObjectInterface`), plus other concerning situations (e.g., `"deep.property"` is not assignable to `[K1, K2]`; did you mean `["deep", "property"]`?).  Please consider editing.

Comment: Currying seems to be the good answer but I can't figure out how to do this working with overloading.

Comment: You've changed the code so that you're passing in a value of type `T`, thus no longer requiring partial type parameter inference (you are inferring `T` and `K`).  So what is your problem now?  If I check your code in my IDE I only see that you've neglected to annotate the return type of your overload call signatures (e.g., `: void`)  Does your example accurately reproduce your problem?

Comment: I'm just trying to make this working without having to pass objectType parameter to updateDeepObjectProperty method as I dont need it. I tried currying but I can't get it working. Thank's

Comment: Like [this](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8CwAoa0CuAHAJmAC4CmAIiSbgPIBGAVicEQAoBO8uJbRAngDwAVAHwAKAJQAuaPwDSARmgkAHqQB2+GAGsSveADNoggDTRZAJiWqSG7boNGA2goC6YjFiy5iAC2nP5UwsXYw9PADcwEGwSaUEAl2dzFzDxaABeYWhw+ABLfABuMLxCUgoqOkZmdk5uPiExKRkFK3VNaB09QxFRMK9ff1dQzAiomLiE1IysnPyikZLickoaBiZWDi4eXgkUPug2EiJsNjVoUW8iP2gwNV5TSOjYm7u0zJRoAHoAKmhcgFtcCBoD5uCRoN9PtAAL7zLDQjAI9AYXJqUhsfRgYDgyrrACSaO4mOxexG+BW0jQIy8mzqvGkamw-1o3DhMPmSIwoEgMAAQmA2KSablIqRoPpEBloGoSAB3OCICRs+BqACqBCWgh8qIA5qJHuNpUyWWwmrN8ELPFdchAAHQS+C2xZlFa46q07b8N1EAno4kkRq9ameRwAInJVFDplDuA9fFDIX2WANJH24jZSKRQA)?

Comment: Why not make `Foo` generic, though, like [this](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD28A8AVAfNA3gWAFDWmHgDsIAXAJwFdgz4KAKAByoCMQBLYaJi+JgFzQUASiwBfPASpMAJmDIBTACKLFTJAGkAjNEUAPJcVkwA1ooCe8AGbCANNE0AmPYcXGzlm8IDaOgLpozAoAFkJ+2g7O-g4AbmAgVIpCKBH+fk7+IkKx8ByyANxS0DLySqrqWroGRibQ5la26MFkYdBpcQlJKWnZ0Ln5RfglcgoqakwtbWDEFp2JydAzFmKYAPQAVBwAtkwgG2uSuEccxEoU1mDAitAA8qwAVoq0AJJnihdXNzjDshNCmB4fCYHzIFiExCo21YHwK0HEQyOoEgMAAQmAKFhivBHkJ7k9Xu9PtdoABeLDQP7qAFA-ig8HQXTieFDAjWRBk6DERQAdzgiAYrQ4EAAdDiHiJWdASABVUZKFAhU4AcwY8QWEKhMIofQGsixwwIQtF7PgItKYwqkx8ACIqUwbQ4bbw6RQwTaYv0uopJcUjkcgA)?

Comment: I'm happy to make these an answer if I understand what you're trying to do.  The generic version seems like the right approach since you presumably actually need an object of type `T` somewhere to modify.  The currying thing will work but I don't understand the use case that would make that preferable to a generic class.

Comment: Overloading is not working with your first example:

Comment: [link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#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)