# Typescript inference based on transformation function return value

Tags: typescript

Let me establish basic types first (might be wrong).

```
type TResolver<TData = any, TResolved = TData> = (data: TData) => TResolved

function fetchData<TData = any, TResolved = TData>(
  resolver: TResolver<TData, TResolved>
): Promise<TResolved | null>
```

The core idea is to a have a fetch function utilizing caching mechanism which returns the previous result while fetching next one (refetch or different input). On top of that, the resolver can transform data into a different shape for the cache so the transformation runs only once per data.

```
type AboutUser = {
  user: {
    name: string
  }
}

fetchData<AboutUser>({ resolver: (data) => data.user }).then(user => {
  // user should be typed properly here
})
```

**[Full code in the Playground.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgShAzgewDYDcICcA8MAiAhsIVALxSEB2IANLAihhACbmxEkB87AFC8UIAuDoICU5HvCRpMLALAAoJQGNkVRMCgsIAM0IBXVMEazs7PJ0Jd+gkQXGTtgpUsKIQVFVF0GvwAEt1HwhgFQALK0tBdmo6BhlmNgoHbl4lKCgsRMwsdh19IxMc83cEplzoknppCtYuJTERAAUsZABbAMQIPFMkqAAfKCojVB4AbwyoNQ0tcedqqFRkQhYAqgBzKABfWIB3QgCtLD8AMVCIquteMSmZzSgN0IBhQgjWK3Zu4AMwV-feNk6lhbopMtkflgqI8Xm9wh9BLxlqt1ht6AISKDtq5FL5-EFoScqOcwuErjYJJMwVlQgYoVAqZlMsi1psRMAThBaFNMhjhAzdmVUoQptjFGKlHiVIFgt9fv94Vcan05DYgWYsPYVdgleUzCwuJSpgB6Y3TOGo7ShQ6oRBLPRaZAGLS6ZB5ABG2XQRxAU1QoXN7xYWpKbCGI1QqHYEdQUwhdOhSJWrI2IndyDQEGo6LsokxTkZTICuigSZRmyN1KZNMh0JUcNYPJ2TfrQfY6uYWFsmKb8fprfhCmpYolilAkCgAEF086AKrdPIUQsGBciQuZKiEdoQESaLCo0VKUe6C6RQQ4adO4Dz7A2buECRkHh8gB0K+wYhfwHhVF478XEwmma-5QIg4ROqgbDutA46sFAYBtJAWCoCAUDwtkR5iEAA)**

[image: type error]

I am well aware I could just do `fetchData<AboutUser, AboutUser["user"]>(...)` which will fix the problem in this case. However, transformations are usually much wilder so I would love to have inference working for me here.

**Clarification**

In response to https://stackoverflow.com/a/58159700/902813 I want to add that in reality there are auto-generated abstractions (based on server schema) which take care of generating and attaching proper types. So instead of `fetchData<AboutUser>` I would rather call `fetchUser` which already carries the correct type.

If resolver would be expected to specify that type again, it would kinda beat the purpose of the whole thing.

**SOLVED**

I've decided for an alternative approach which utilizes the currying in a sort, but still feels natural enough.

Comment: It is inferring but because of `TResolved = TData` your are calling `fetchData<AboutUser, AboutUser>(..)`

Comment: So you want to *specify* `TData` but *infer* `TResolved`?  That's [partial type parameter inference](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10571) and it isn't currently supported directly in TypeScript.  If so, I'd be inclined to close this as a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57135846/make-overpropobj-function-interface-with-one-param) or the like.

Comment: The workaround here might be `const fetchData = <TData = any>() =>
  async function fetchData<TResolved = TData>(resolver = defaultResolver as TResolver<TData, TResolved>): Promise<TResolved | null> {...}` and then `fetchData<AboutUser>()(data => data.user).then(user => {...})`

Comment: I don't insist on having TResolver like that, I just don't know a better way if there is any. But it does really seem that TypeScript cannot do that just yet. Oh well and I was thinking how trivial this surely is.

Comment: @jcalz Yea, I read about currying workaround, but that seems rather unintuitive just because of the types.

Answer (score 1):

Change it to:

```
fetchData({ resolver: (data: AboutUser) => data.user }).then(user => {
  // user should be typed properly here
})
```

Comment: Thanks, but I hope there is some other way. See OP for clarification, please.