# Infer the return type of a function as param in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a function `getData` that expects an optional parameter: a function for transforming data.
Inside the `getData` function, I somehow get the raw data (details are not important).

I would like Typescript to correctly infer the return type of `getData` based on the type of transform function passed to `getData`

```
function request<T>():T {
    return "12" as unknown as T
}

function getData<Input>(transform?: undefined): Input
function getData<Input, Output>(transform: (data: Input) => Output): Output
function getData<Input, Output>(transform?: (data: Input) => Output) {
    const data = request<Input>()
    if (transform) {
        return transform(data)
    }

    return data
}
const outputAsString = getData<string>()
const outputAsNumber = getData<string, number>(data => data.length)
```

This code works. What I would like to avoid is passing that second generic in the second example as I think it can be inferred from transform function return type.
However, when I do:

```
const outputAsNumber = getData<string>(data => data.length)
```

I get explicity `any` on data and `Argument of type '(data: any) => any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'undefined'.`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make overProp<Obj> function interface with one param](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57135846/make-overpropobj-function-interface-with-one-param)

Comment: You want to be able to specify one type parameter (`Input`) and have the compiler infer the other one (`Output`), but TypeScript does not support such partial type parameter inference.  There are workarounds, shown in linked issue.

Comment: thank you jcalz, I will read the other issue (do you have a job or just spend your time here? )

Comment: @jcalz I tried your suggestion but unfortunately I can't get that work. I added function overload but it seems I can't pass a transform function. 
I pasted my solution to codesandbox because typescript playground produces long URLS:
https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-davinci-9b0f7

Comment: The outer fn should return an overloaded inner fn, not vice versa.  Like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=5&ssc=1&pln=18&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAJwKYEcSoM5QDwAqAfABQCUAXIgYgN4CwAUIiyqlCMkiQEQCMAJh6IAhtkTgA1mDgB3MGVHiCAbiYBfJk1CRYCRAHN2AERFQRAYU7IYqACZ4AkmAAOIKKUUNmrNBy6IOtDwSHgA8u5uHiRQyCJg2MBwyAC2APxUJHZmIlTOUYoAvESIEVAFdEys1YgQCLiI2eaIhWyYOPj57p5qPjWIMMCIMXEJSaleVf01fpxIsfGJySlZOWS904iajFP9swFNIhus6kqVfTXkea7ux-3hkd0ji+MpmYfXFcWlj1CUP+Vbrstr1tkw6gkoIYTDkWtCoKZzFZkDZ7HhcDYwAYeuD6lC4L8AILYADKsRgWLhRgROXIKkQuMhiAJgKgxIAciAUgAjVDIKkw8wkVbmKgYikGIolQ4AOgANqgsVAABbrBmMIA).

Comment: @jcalz thank you very much. I don't quite get the subtle difference between your working solution and mine yet but I learned the clever use of `as { }` in your example