# Creating a Key/Value pair via factory only allows properties and associated property type values from a class

Tags: typescript

So if I have say a `car`:

```js
public class Car 
{
  ManufacturedYear: number;
  Manufacturer: string;
}
```

I'd like to be able to build a strongly typed tree of criteria (which would be serialized to json and either user client side for filtering or server side for a SQL where clause).  Here is what I have so far:

```js
export class FilterFactory {
  private constructor() {
  }

  public static createFilter<TModel, TKey extends keyof TModel>(
    key: TKey,
    value: TModel[TKey],
  ): IFilterCriteria<TModel, TKey> {
    return new FilterCriteria(key, value);
  }
}

export interface IFilterCriteria<TModel, TKey extends keyof TModel> {
  property?: TKey;
  value?: TModel[TKey];
  operator? : 'and' | 'or';  //tbd enum
  criterias?: ?? 
}

class FilterCriteria<TModel, TKey extends keyof TModel>
  implements IFilterCriteria<TModel, TKey>
{
  public property?: TKey;
  public value?: TModel[TKey];
  public operator? : 'and' | 'or';  //tbd enum
  public criterias?: ?? 

  constructor() {}
}
```

[Codepen Example](https://codepen.io/erikphilips/pen/LYYqmeJ?editors=0010)

So the following works:

```js
var noerror = FilterFactory.createFilter<Car, 'ManufacturedYear'>('ManufacturedYear', 2008);

var expectederror = FilterFactory.createFilter<Car, 'ManufacturedYear'>('ManufacturedYear', 'asdf');
```

What I can't figure out is how to remove the redundancy of specifying the key for both the generic and the parameter.  So my code would be one of the following:

```js
var noerror = FilterFactory.createFilter<Car, 'ManufacturedYear'>(2008);
// or
var noerror = FilterFactory.createFilter<Car>('ManufacturedYear', 2008);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make overProp<Obj> function interface with one param](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57135846/make-overpropobj-function-interface-with-one-param)

Comment: The code here doesn't constitute a [mcve]; you've got the `public` modifier in multiple inappropriate locations.  Please consider editing the code so that it can be dropped into a standalone IDE like [the TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) and demonstrate your issue with no unrelated errors.  Good luck!

Comment: What are your thoughts about passing the `Car` constructor to `createFilter()`, even though you haven't shown it to be necessary, like `FilterFactory.createFilter(Car, 'ManufacturedYear', 2008)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite as elegant as I hoped but it's not bad really, it's at least readable:

TLDR:

```js
class Car {
  ManufacturedYear: number;
  Manufacturer: string;
}

const manuYearFilter = FilterFactory.with<Car>().create("ManufacturedYear", 2009);
```

implementation:

```js
export interface IFilter {
}

export class FilterFactory<TModel> {
  private constructor() {
  }

  public  create<TKey extends keyof TModel>(
    key: TKey,
    value: TModel[TKey],
  ): IFilter {
    return new Filter(key, value);
  }

  public static with<TModel>() {
    return new FilterFactory<TModel>();
  }
}

class Filter<TModel, TKey extends keyof TModel>
  implements IFilter
{
  constructor(
    public property: TKey,
    public value: TModel[TKey],
  ) {
  }
}
```